# Animate Listview to increase in size

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I am trying to get an animation to work when I scroll my `ListView`. What I would like is when a user scrolls down to see more of the entries in the list the layout above it (A `RelativeLayout`) will shrink in size. I would like the `RelativeLayout` to only go as small as a quarter of the screen and only go as large as half the screen when scrolling.

The code I have now is jumpy and looks bad. I need a better solution to this issue

Here is the code I have so far

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if(mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem){
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenHeight = size.y;

        System.out.println("Screen Height / 2: " + (screenHeight / 2));
        System.out.println("Balance Height 1: " + relBal.getHeight());
        if(relBal.getHeight() > (screenHeight / 2)){
            newBalHeight = (screenHeight / 2);
        }
        else {
            newBalHeight = relBal.getHeight() + 100;
        }

        System.out.println("Balance Height 2: " + newBalHeight);

        ResizeAnimation resize = new ResizeAnimation(relBal, relBal.getWidth(), relBal.getHeight(), relBal.getWidth(), newBalHeight);
        relBal.startAnimation(resize);
}
if(mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem){
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenHeight = size.y;

    System.out.println("Screen Height / 4: " + (screenHeight / 4));
    System.out.println("Balance Height: " + relBal.getHeight());
    if(relBal.getHeight() < (screenHeight / 4)){
                    newBalHeight = (screenHeight / 4);
    }
    else {
                    newBalHeight = relBal.getHeight() - 100;
    }

    System.out.println("Balance Height 2: " + newBalHeight);
    ResizeAnimation resize = new ResizeAnimation(relBal, relBal.getWidth(), relBal.getHeight(), relBal.getWidth(), newBalHeight);
    relBal.startAnimation(resize);
}
mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
```

}

This is what my page looks like

[image]

I want it to look like this when I scroll to see more items

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just resizing the view without animating? `onScroll` should be called often enough to not require animation.

Comment: @dcharms I think the issue is getting the scrolling direction correct. This doesnt work well when using that scrolllistener

Comment: There are many libraries that can serve your purpose without coding complex Translate Animations:
You can use [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), as it's docs says you can set an anchor point somewhere in the middle of the screen using setAnchorPoint to allow an intermediate expanded state for the panel (similar to Google Maps). 
Or use [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Comment: Use parallax scrolling. See this link
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/70

Comment: @BigT, did you find a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put up an example project at https://github.com/ramanadv/ShrinkingHeader . Below is the logic I have used , its a little shaky because I haven't actually taken much care there. This is just to give you a direction . Don't use animation because OnScroll is called enough times to give you a smooth height change transition.

```
    list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int scroll = getScroll(list);
            changeHeight(price,scroll);
            System.out.println("scroll "+scroll);
        }
    });

}

protected int getScroll(ListView listView) {// as list recycles views , getscrollY wont give us how much it has scrolled, hence we use this hack
    firstChildInList = listView.getChildAt(0);
    if(firstChildInList == null)return 0;
    return -firstChildInList.getTop() + listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * firstChildInList.getHeight();
}

protected void setHeightForView(View v ,int h){ //  you need to set params to change height 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.height = h;
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
}
protected void changeHeight(View view,int scroll) { // this is a simple logic , this is a little shaky , but its simple , you can smoothen from here
    int priceHeight = price.getHeight();
    if(priceHeight>=screenHeight/4 && priceHeight<=screenHeight/2){
        setHeightForView(view, screenHeight/2-scroll);
    }
    else if(priceHeight < screenHeight/4){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In OnScroll get the position of the child from the top and then according to the value change top margin for the headingView:

```
private OnScrollListener scrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {
        private boolean userScrolled = false;

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == 1) {
                userScrolled = true;
            }
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (userScrolled) {
                secondChildFromTop = view.getChildAt(1).getTop();// From this value it is going to be easy to know if the scrolling is happening up or down
             methodThatChangesTheTopMarginForYourView(secondChildFromTop);
}
}
}
private void methodThatChangesTheTopMarginForYourView(int value){
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
        (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)yourHeadingView.getLayoutParams();
        //some mathematical logic with the value param.
        params.topMargin = //add negative value so the view goes outside of the screen, and the orginal value to get it back in original position


}
```